# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar un objeto correctamente en un array en base a un atributo? (Java)

Tags: java

he intentado ordenar un arreglo de menor a mayor utilizando el metodo burbuja, el array es de objetos, y para mi es necesario ordenarlo dichos objetos en base a el atributo Llegada que tienen, sin embargo por mas que lo he intentado a la hora de desplegar el arreglo ordenado no consigo que este este en orden aqui el codigo: los valores del atributo Llamada son 4,0,1,8,12,6 por lo que al ordenarse deberia desplegarse como 0,1,4,6,8,12 sin embargo al desplegarlo recibo 12 1 4 8 6 0

```
private Proceso[] OrdenarArregloLlegada(Proceso[] ProcesosTabla) {
   Proceso ProcesosOrdenLlegada[]= ProcesosTabla; 
   System.out.print("   ");
   for(int z=0;z<ProcesosOrdenLlegada.length;z++){
       System.out.print(ProcesosOrdenLlegada[z].getLlegada());
   }
   System.out.print("   ");
   Proceso aux;
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"recibe: "+ProcesosTabla.length);
     
   for(int i=0;i<ProcesosTabla.length;i++){
    for(int x=0;x<ProcesosTabla.length-1;x++){
       
            if(ProcesosOrdenLlegada[x].getLlegada()>ProcesosOrdenLlegada[x+1].getLlegada()){
                aux=ProcesosOrdenLlegada[x];
                ProcesosOrdenLlegada[x]=ProcesosOrdenLlegada[x+1];
                ProcesosOrdenLlegada[x+1]=aux;
            }
       
     }
   }
   
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Esto funciona");
for(int i=0;i<ProcesosTabla.length;i++){
    System.out.print(ProcesosTabla[i].getLlegada());
    
  
}
 return ProcesosOrdenLlegada; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es importante que entiendas que un array NO se pasa a un método por su valor, sino por su referencia. Con lo cual, no tiene sentido que crees un nuevo array, el cual ordenarás y devolverás, si con el propio array parametrizado que quieras ordenar ya te hará ese trabajo sin necesidad de devolver nada.

Si quieres mantener el array original intacto, el método debe CLONAR el array anterior y trabajar con el nuevo array, para conservar los datos del original:

```
private static Proceso[] OrdenarArregloLlegada(Proceso[] ProcesosTabla) {
    System.out.println("Array desordenado en método");
    
    Proceso[] nuevoArray = ProcesosTabla.clone();
    
    System.out.print("   ");
    for (int z = 0; z < nuevoArray.length; z++) {
        System.out.print(nuevoArray[z].getLlegada() + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("   ");
    Proceso aux;

    for (int i = 0; i < nuevoArray.length; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < nuevoArray.length-1; x++) {

            if (nuevoArray[x].getLlegada() > nuevoArray[x + 1].getLlegada()) {
                aux = nuevoArray[x];
                nuevoArray[x] = nuevoArray[x + 1];
                nuevoArray[x + 1] = aux;
            }

        }
    }
    
    return nuevoArray;

}
```

Es importante que al realizar la llamada, crees un array donde se recoja la referencia al array creado en el método (en el main, por ejemplo):

```
    Proceso[] arrayFinal = OrdenarArregloLlegada(procesosOriginal);

    System.out.println("Array ordenado");
    
    for (Proceso p : arrayFinal) {
        System.out.println(p.getLlegada() + " ");
    }
    
    System.out.println("Array original");

    for(Proceso p: procesosOriginal) {
        System.out.println(p.getLlegada() + " ");
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracías, sin embargo la razón por la que duplique el array, es porque necesito conservar el que le brindo al metodo tal y como esta, ya que el orden que presenta en un inicio tambien me sera de utilidad posteriormente, y disculpa, aun estoy aprendiendo :c

Comment: Disculpa, no sabía que querías conservar el original. Aquí tienes la edición, simplemente haces un clone del array parametrizado en un array nuevo y lo devuelves. Recuerda guardar la referencia al nuevo array en la llamada. Un saludo y tranquilo, nadie nace aprendido :)

Comment: Muchas gracías, me haz sido de mucha ayuda :D

Comment: Para eso estamos :D si puedes, marca la respuesta como útil para que otros puedan aprovecharla en el futuro ;)